# Increase pycharm speed

Tags: python, performance, configuration, pycharm

I want to increase the speed of my pyCharm, in particular the speed of the debugger (when I am using debugger it is VERY slow).

my `pycharm.vmoptions` are :

```
-Xms1024m #changed from 128
-Xmx2048m #changed from 1000
-XX:MaxPermSize=500m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=360m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

What should I add to increase the speed of pyCharm in general and the debugger?
Should I run the config file somehow for this changes to apply or does it occur automatically?

Comment: @KlausD. What do you mean?

Comment: In `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views` you can untick `Enable auto expressions in Variables view` and other boxes which I think consume some time but are very useful for debugging purpose.

Comment: You can also Clear the cache of the Python debugger in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Debugger`